# How do i create a "list" of groups read from an hdf5 files

Tags: python, hdf5

I want to create a python list of the names of the "groups" from a HDF5 file.  I am able to do it with the following code BUT "groups" is a global variable and I want to make it a local variable so I can read multiple HDF5 files and have a local list of groups for that file and not for all files.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import h5py

# this is global and not what I want - want this to be local
groups=[]

# use with visit items   ob is info about group or dataset
def printname2(name,ob):
    print "\t",name,' ==> ',ob
    groups.append(name)       # i want to replace this, how do I save "ob" in a list???

def print_attrs(f,s):
    print '\n'+s,' ',f[s]
    for i in range( len(f[s].attrs.keys()) ):
        print '\t',f[s].attrs.keys()[i],'\t\t',f[s].attrs.values()[i]


filename2 = './testFile.hdf5'
f = h5py.File(filename2, 'r')


print 'f.visit traverses recursively through the file structure'
#groups[]   --- I tried to re-define groups here but doesn't work...
f.visititems(printname2)  # groups is updated ; fix this

print '\nNumber of groups ',len(groups),'\n'

#        
attributes=[]
key=[]
for g in groups:
    key.append ( f[g].attrs.keys() )

print '\\nDUMP ALL GROUPS AND ATTRIBUTES PARSED ", len(groups)
for g in groups:
    print_attrs(f,g)
```

Comment: Create a function and encapsulate all that behaviour into it? In python you can define functions within functions creating local scopes.